# in unix FOR LOOP showing syntax error (error token is "<")

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix, for-loop

i want to compare data between two headings in a file.

By first `awk` command i fetched the headings in `temp.txt`. `$z` holds the number of headings in file. Now i'm using `for-loop` for comparing two consecutive headings with `awk` command but following error is showing..

> **line 5: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")**

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '/^[A-Z]+[:_]/ {print $1}' abc.txt > temp.txt
z= wc -l temp.txt | cut -d " " -f1
echo $z
for((i=1;i<$z;i++))
do
A=$(awk "NR=='$i'" ref.txt )

B=$(awk "NR=='$i+1'" ref.txt )

C=echo$(sed -n -e /$A/,/$B/p /home/aniruddh/abc.txt > temp.txt)
awk '/[A-Z]+-[0-9]/ {print $1}' temp.txt
echo
done
```

Comment: what does `echo $z` print?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose command with `$(...)`

```
z=$(wc -l temp.txt | cut -d " " -f1)
```

Comment: Please avoid the antique backticks and use $(...) instead. The last one is easy to nest  and better to read, independent of font.

Comment: or `z=$(wc -l <temp.txt)`

Comment: I've removed the suggestion to use backticks. It is one thing to recognize what they mean if you see them, but quite another to suggest using them where they were previously unknown.

Comment: The script has a large number of unrelated errors which at least you should mention.

Answer (score 2):

Since error is on line 5 so please change following in your script:

```
z=$(wc -l temp.txt | cut -d " " -f1)
```